# Dynamic Authentication and Authorization with Shiro

Tags: security, jakarta-ee, jpa, shiro

I've a application ( JSP + EJB3 + JPA). I want to secures it with Shiro. Accounts, roles and permissions must be dynamics. ie Modifiable inside the application. Passwords are encrypted in SHA1
This is my code.

Shiro.ini :

```
[main]
customSecurityRealm=cismaa.ssae.supervision.ihm.security.SecurityRealm
# any object property is automatically configurable in Shiro.ini file
customSecurityRealm.jndiDataSourceName=UtilisateurService

customSecurityRealm.authenticationQuery = select password, from utilisateur where name     = ?
sha1Matcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.HashedCredentialsMatcher
sha1Matcher.hashAlgorithmName=SHA-1
customSecurityRealm.credentialsMatcher = $sha1Matcher


securityManager.realms = $customSecurityRealm
authc.loginUrl = /loginservlet
# name of request parameter with username; if not present filter assumes 'username'
authc.usernameParam = login
# name of request parameter with password; if not present filter assumes 'password'
authc.passwordParam = password
# redirect after successful login
authc.successUrl  = /menuficheservlet
# replace form authentication filter with verbose filter
authc = cismaa.ssae.supervision.ihm.security.VerboseFormAuthenticationFilter
# request parameter with login error information; if not present filter assumes 'shiroLoginFailure'
authc.failureKeyAttribute=simpleShiroApplicationLoginFailure

[urls]

/layout/unicorn/resources/** = anon
/** = authc
```

SecurityRealm :

```
public class SecurityRealm extends JdbcRealm {

@EJB
private IUtilisateurService users;
private Utilisateur util;



public SecurityRealm() {  
    super();  
    /*InitialContext ic;
    try {
        ic = new InitialContext();
        users = (IUtilisateurService) ic.lookup("UtilisateurService");
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }*/

}  

protected String jndiDataSourceName;

public String getJndiDataSourceName() {
    return jndiDataSourceName;
}

public void setJndiDataSourceName(String jndiDataSourceName) {
    this.jndiDataSourceName = jndiDataSourceName;
    this.users = getDataSourceFromJNDI(jndiDataSourceName);
}

private IUtilisateurService getDataSourceFromJNDI(String jndiDataSourceName) {
    try {
        InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
        return (IUtilisateurService) ic.lookup(jndiDataSourceName);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        throw new AuthorizationException(e);
    }
}

private String getPasswordForUser(String email) throws AuthenticationException {  

    util = users.findbyEmail(email);
    if(util == null) {
        throw new AuthenticationException("Utilisateur " + email + " introuvable");
    }
    return util.getMotDePasseUtilisateur();
}  

@Override
protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(
        AuthenticationToken token) throws AuthenticationException {
    UsernamePasswordToken upToken = (UsernamePasswordToken) token;  
    String email = upToken.getUsername();
    // Null username is invalid  
    if (email == null) {  
        throw new AccountException("Null usernames are not allowed by this realm.");  
    }
    String password = getPasswordForUser(email); 
    if (password == null) {  
        throw new UnknownAccountException("No account found for user [" + email + "]");  
    }  
    return new SimpleAuthenticationInfo(email, password, getName());
}

@Override
protected Set<String> getRoleNamesForUser(Connection conn, String email)
        throws SQLException {
    Role roles = util.getRole();
    Set<String> rolesName =  new HashSet<String>();
    rolesName.add(roles.getNomRole());
    return rolesName;
}
```

}

Web.xml

```
<!-- SHIRO !-->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

With this nothing happen when i try to connect to my app. I can see all the content of the app.

What i've missed?

Answer (score 1):

In the shiro manual it says implicit assignment of realms is discouraged and may be removed, so perhaps it is already removed. Try adding the following line to shiro.ini:

```
securityManager.realms = $customSecurityRealm
```

Manual: http://shiro.apache.org/realm.html#Realm-ImplicitAssignment

Comment: Same with this line. Nothing happen. Shiro doesn't validate the connexion. I can fill login form with any string, and it pass.

Comment: Can you share the rest of your config? Do you have an [urls] section and all that?

Comment: OK i find thé problème. I have sécurité avons train tag info web.XML that override shiro.ini. i removed it and all is ok

Comment: This is my last configuration. Now shiro redirects every request upon loginServlet. But when i proceed login, nothing happen, i come back on my login page. Shiro don't call customSecurityRealm.